# ValueMember from ComboBox.Items[i] using WinForms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I fill out a ComboBox using below code:

```
cbxLines.DisplayMember = "Value";
cbxLines.ValueMember = "Key";
cbxLines.DataSource = new BindingSource(GetProductionLines(), null);

private Dictionary<int, string> GetProductionLines()
```

Now I want to fill out a ListView with every `DisplayMember` from the ComboBox among other info:

```
lvSelectedSetup.Items.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i <= cbxLines.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
     ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
     item.SubItems.Add(cbxLines.Items[i].ToString());  <-- How to Get DisplayMember
     item.SubItems.Add(cbxFromDate.Text);
     item.SubItems.Add(cbxToDate.Text);
     lvSelectedSetup.Items.Add(item);
}
```

But I don't know how to get either the `ValueMember` or `DisplayMember` from the ComboBox.

I was trying doing the following, but get stuck:

```
item.SubItems.Add(cbxLines.Items[i].GetType().GetProperty(cbxLines.ValueMember).GetValue(cbxLines,null))
```

Any Advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gets the key in the key/value pair.

```
   ((KeyValuePair<int, string>)cbxLines.Items[i]).Key
```

Gets the value in the key/value pair.

```
((KeyValuePair<int, string>)cbxLines.Items[i]).Value
```

Comment: Outstanding! By the way, I've figured it out how to make my approach work: `item.SubItems.Add(cbxLines.Items[0].GetType().GetProperty(cbxLines.DisplayMember).GetValue(cbxLines.Items[i], null).ToString());` it is a bit longer of course :)

Comment: @Somebody: it is also a _lot_ slower than doing it the way Jacob shows. Avoid reflection if you can. And one usually can. Note also that you really only need this for the `DisplayMember` member. You can get the `ValueMember` member's value straight from the `ComboBox.SelectedValue` property.