# Winforms- How to get ValueMember of Combobox(i)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a combobox assigned with a data source:

```
Public Sub DataBind(ByVal table As DataTable, ByVal DisplayMember As String, ByVal ValueMember As String)
    cbox.DataSource = table
    cbox.DisplayMember = DisplayMember
    cbox.ValueMember = ValueMember
End Sub
```

I want to iterate each item in the ComboboxItems and get its ValueMember and DisplayMember.
I watched this post [ValueMember from ComboBox.Items[i] using WinForms c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628022/valuemember-from-combobox-itemsi-using-winforms-c-sharp)

so I tried

```
For I As Integer = 0 To cbox.Items.Count - 1
  Dim val = DirectCast(cbox.Items(I), KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)).Value
Next
```

but I get an invalid cast exception saying that the specified cast is not valid.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Create a `GetItemValue` extension method like [this C# version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38305363/3110834).

Comment: The DisplayMemeber and Valuemember are still in teh DataTable/DataTable, so its not clear what you are playing at

Answer (score 1):

Found another solution to what I was trying to achieve:

```
Dim row As DataRow = DirectCast(cbox.Items(I), DataRowView).Row
Dim val As String = (row(cbox.ValueMember)).ToString()
```